# Permission denied var/run/nginx.pid

Tags: nginx, docker, root

I get the following error:

```
Permission denied var/run/nginx.pid
```

Inside my nginx docker container the problem is the user running is unprivileged user with a **random userid** (forced by my company security) how to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the PID file location in `nginx` configuration by adding / editing the `pid` variable in configuration.

You should put the file in location where the random user id can write, like the user's home directory.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on how you fixed it